Hilbert's program participants
Does anyone know about the Hilbert's program specifically? I want to know who participated in the program, and how it was progressed. Hilbert's Program: A program which tried to explain mathematics with a single formalized axiom theory

Can you tell us what research you have already done and what you know since otherwise people will spend time telling you things you already know?

See Hilbert’s Program. The main Hilbert's collaborators: Paul Bernays, Wilhelm Ackermann, John von Neumann, Heinrich Behmann and Jacques Herbrand, up to Gödel and Gentzen.

And see Paolo Mancosu, The Adventure of Reason: Interplay Between Philosophy of Mathematics and Mathematical Logic, 1900–1940 (Oxford University Press, 2010)

"Hilbert's Program: A program which tried to explain mathematics with a single formalized axiom theory..." Not exactly: "Hilbert’s Program calls for a formalization of all of mathematics in axiomatic form, together with a proof that this axiomatization of mathematics is consistent. The consistency proof itself was to be carried out using only what Hilbert called “finitary” methods."

And see Wilfried Sieg, Hilbert's Programs and Beyond (Oxford UP, 2103) as well as Hilbert's programs: 1917-1922 (1999)
